# Iterator to array Java

Tags: java, arrays, excel, iterator

I'm working on a little app with Java on Netbeans, and I need to export the data of Excel file to an array and then work on this array.
To get the excel I use Apache POI and I can show the value of the excel file in the consol.

However, I need to put it in an array, and for the moment I don't know how to work with the Iterator because I am getting the excel data into an iterator.

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(pathConfig1));
//File
Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(nbSheet1);
//Get index sheet user

Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
int nbLine= sheet.getLastRowNum() +1; 
//Number of Lines

int nbCol = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum(); 
// Number of columns

String [][]data= new String[nbLine][nbCol];
//Array for the data
```

From this point I don't really know how to export the data in my array...
Any idea ?

I thought to use 2 loop for but I don't know how to increment my Iterator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what I've understood, you want to store the every cell values in each row in an array right? If that's the case yes, you're right to use 2 loops and the iterator is optional in this case. I've rewritten your code and hope it helps.

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(pathConfig1));
// Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
// Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator(); 
int nbLine = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
int nbCol = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
String[][] data = new String[nbLine][nbCol];
for (int i = 0; i < nbLine; i++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < nbCol; j++) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
        data[i][j] = cell.toString();
    }
}
// Display
for (int i = 0; i < nbLine; i++) {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    int j = 0;
    for (; j < nbCol - 1; j++) {
        buff.append(data[i][j]);
        buff.append(",");
    }
    buff.append(data[i][j]);
    System.out.println(buff.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specific library you're using, but an easy way to use iterators is in a for each loop

Something like

```
for (Sheet sheet : workbook.sheetIterator()) {
    for (Row row : sheet.rowIterator()) {
        data[row][col] = //row.getCellValue()? Like I said, I don't know this library
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like that too at the beginning, first time I use this library! Thanks for try btw ;)